# Newbie to Dutch Oven

Tags: pasta

I just bought a dutch oven and was wondering if I can use that instead of a larger pot for pasta. Can you also bake casseroles in it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can use it for other cooking.  They are pretty ballistic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are very versatile! Is it cast iron? If so, I would always rub it down with a tsp of oil on the inside before using it, and also if its not ENAMELED do not cook anything acidic in it like tomato sauce for example. If it is cast iron, don't put it in the dishwasher. Just rinse well with hot water, and put it on low heat to dry completely. If you must, use a little soap and water and hand wash it. Cast iron is amazing.